# Using Python to read .CSV files and then compare the columns/rows

Tags: python, list, csv

I am currently trying to develop a program that reads data from a text file, and returns the pair of employees that has worked the most time together. I decided to it in a .CSV format, as that is still a plain text format, but seperated with comas.

Example:

```
EmpID,ProjectID,DateFrom,DateTo
1,A,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,B,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
2,C,2014-01-07,2016-03-07
3,B,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,C,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
1,A,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
2,C,2015-07-09,2019-01-19
3,B,2013-11-13,2014-03-13
4,C,2016-02-14,NULL
5,D,2014-03-15,2015-11-09
```

Now, I learned how to read .CSV files, but I am not sure on what is the best way for the thing after (the comparing of values, etc). For now, I decided that this is the cleanest option:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

I just want a piece of advice, if the best way to go would be with comparing indexes of the list. I was also thinking about dictionaries, but I am not sure, hence the reason I am asking here :) And SQL is not an option, even though it would be so easy with it. Sorry if this is a bad question, but I am currently learning Python and this is quite an important task for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally create an `Employee` class and use each line to create an Employee object. This reduces complexity because it's much easier to refer to, say, an employee's id as `employee.id` instead of an index of a list or a key in a dictionary, and `Employee`'s methods could deal with the logic afterwards. This of course requires you to learn at least some object oriented programming basics in Python, however.

Comment: I highly recommend using pandas. It makes manipulating the data table a lot easier. Pandas will render the csv file as a dataframe and you can specify which column is the index.

Comment: I second the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) vote, the library is set up specifically to handle this kind of problem. I've linked the `read_csv` method

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from what you wrote, I think what you need is something like this:

```
#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('data.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")

for item in csv_file:
#do your work
```

maybe you can look at Pandas too if you have large Data. It ll be more efficient to work with Pandas in that Case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` package to check total time elapsed. Create a list of people in the csv file, then sort the list based on the elapsed time. for the first 8 rows of csv file (because NULL is undefined!):

```
1,A,2014-11-01,2015-05-01
2,B,2013-12-06,2014-10-06
2,C,2014-01-07,2016-03-07
3,B,2015-06-04,2017-09-04
5,C,2014-10-01,2015-12-01
1,A,2013-03-07,2015-11-07
```

You can use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_list = list()
    for line in file:      
        list_ = line.split(',')
        dt1 = datetime.strptime(list_[2], '%Y-%M-%d')
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(list_[3][:10], '%Y-%M-%d')
        my_list.append(list_[:2] + [dt2-dt1])
        my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
print(my_list)
```

output:

```
[['3', 'B', datetime.timedelta(days=364, seconds=85920)], ['1', 'A', datetime.timedelta(days=364, seconds=86040)], ['2', 'B', datetime.timedelta(days=364, seconds=86280)], ['5', 'C', datetime.timedelta(days=365, seconds=120)], ['2', 'C', datetime.timedelta(days=730, seconds=120)], ['1', 'A', datetime.timedelta(days=730, seconds=480)], ['3', 'B', datetime.timedelta(days=731, seconds=180)], ['2', 'C', datetime.timedelta(days=1470, seconds=86040)]]
```